# Logcat error : "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView" While trying to use ListView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I was building an app using android studio and I was making a list in an xml file using java and I wanted the page to have a lower navigation bar as well.
and it gives me that error

```
    Process: com.example.yourhealthapp, PID: 4695
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yourhealthapp/com.example.yourhealthapp.mainPage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.yourhealthapp:layout/activity_main_page: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3450)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3602)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2067)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.yourhealthapp:layout/activity_main_page: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
        at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1125)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.yourhealthapp.mainPage.onCreate(mainPage.java:16)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1312)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3602)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2067)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:50770', transport: 'socket'
```

my java code for this activity

```
package com.example.yourhealthapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class mainPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
        ArrayList<String> foods = new ArrayList<String>();
        foods.add("foods");
        foods.add("foods");
        foods.add("foods");
        foods.add("foods");

        ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, foods);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
    }
}
```

My xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".mainPage">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_main"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                android:text="What have you eaten today"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/adding_main"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                android:text="Food Adding"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/profile_main"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                android:text="Profile"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ListView>
```

so how should I fix my code to have an array list with items and subitems and a lower navigation bar ?

Comment: Do you have an image for what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with one main Relative layout and add list view and bottom navigation inside that
Like

```
<RelativeLayout with matchparent> 
  <Listview with matchparent with layout above navigation view or your design according />
  <RelativeLayout with navigation bar size and alignparentbottom true. />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OR**

```
<LinearLayout with matchparent and orientation vertical> 
  <Listview with height 0dp and layout weight 1 />
  <RelativeLayout with any fixed height or wrapcontent />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it may help you